# why i can't save scss file of template?

Tags: html, css, sass, atom-editor

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U3Ru.png)
Hi, i try to change scss template bu impossible to save.

Error : /bin/sh : 1: node-sass:not found
and an other.
see picture

no found solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment, so adding this as an answer. Run `npm install --save-dev node-sass` before serving or compiling the code.